# Recommender systems and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

According to Mitchell:

> “A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to some class of tasks T and performance measure P, if its performance at tasks in T , as measured by P , improves with experience E” (Mitchell, 1997) .

If we put this in terms of recommender systems:

**Task**: recommend products

**Experience**: includes the experience of observing a set of examples encoded in a ratings matrix

**Performance**: metric i.e. rmse between real and predicted ratings

Is my approach okay?

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

- For experience:

observing a set of examples encoded in a rating matrix is good, before doing that perform hybrid filtering(content-based filtering + collaborative), from its results 
get insights and do rating matrix if needed.

- Performance:

  use rmse metric for better understanding of accuracy.